# Pyglet ignores alpha channel

Tags: python, graphics, pyglet

I'm trying to make a level editor for a game I'm writing in Python using Pyglet. I want to be able to modify the darkness of any block I place. As such, I have added a `darkness` attribute to the `Block` class. Here is that class:

```
class Block:
    def __init__(self, name, image, wall):
        self.name = name
        self.image = image
        self.wall = wall
        self.darkness = 0

    def set_darkness(self, darkness):
        self.darkness = darkness

    def draw(self, x, y):
        self.image.blit(x, y)
        pyglet.graphics.draw(4, GL_QUADS, ('v2i', (x, y, x + block_width, y, x + block_width, y + block_height, x, y + block_width)), ('c4B', (0, 0, 0, self.darkness) * 4))
```

I am trying to darken an image by drawing a black rectangle on top of it, and then adjusting the transparency of that rectangle. However, no matter what I set `self.darkness` to in `__init__`, the rectangle continues to be completely opaque.
I tried enabling color blending with pyglet.gl by adding this code to the top of my program:

```
from pyglet.gl import *
glEnable(GL_BLEND)
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
```

This changed nothing. I also tried using Pyglet's `SolidColorImagePattern` class to create a black rectangle with the alpha channel set to `self.darkness`, but that also did nothing. How do I make this rectangle transparent?

Comment: Where do you call `glEnable(GL_BLEND)` ...? At the begin of the application or in `draw()`?

Answer (score 1):

For any OpenGL instruction, a valid and current [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) is of need. Of course [pyglet](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) provides an OpenGL context, but the context is created and made current when the pyglet (OpenGL) window is created (see [`pyglet.window`](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/window.html)).

Create the window, before setting up [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending) to solve the issue:

```py
from pyglet.gl import *

window = pyglet.window.Window(400, 400, "OpenGL window")

glEnable(GL_BLEND)
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
```